# bootstrap tagsinput failed to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `Django` application which loads tags in an `input field` using `jquery` as shown in the code. On running the code I have observed that application cannot be able to locate `bootstrap-tagsinput.css` and `bootstrap-tagsinput.js`. Where should I put these files so that they can be detected.

**Error**

```
[28/Feb/2018 12:14:23]  "GET /scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2191
Not Found: /scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js
[28/Feb/2018 12:14:23] "GET /scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2188
Not Found: /scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js
[28/Feb/2018 12:14:23] "GET /scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2188
```

**Project Directory Structure**

```
<project_name>
|--<app_name>
|     |--templates
|            |--index.html
|--<project_name>
|--scripts
|     |--bootstrap-tagsinput.css
|     |--bootstrap-tagsinput.js
|--manage.py
```

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">

    <title>Sample</title>

</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="tagbar" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>

    <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tagbar').tagsinput('add', { "value": 1 ,"text": "Amsterdam"  ,"continent": "Europe"    });
            $('#tagbar').tagsinput('add', { "value": 2 ,"text": "Washington" ,"continent": "America"   });
            $('#tagbar').tagsinput('add', { "value": 3 ,"text": "Sydney"     ,"continent": "Australia" });
            $('#tagbar').tagsinput('add', { "value": 4 ,"text": "Beijing"    ,"continent": "Asia"      });
            $('#tagbar').tagsinput('add', { "value": 5 ,"text": "Cairo"      ,"continent": "Africa"    });
         });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django you need to place your static files (css, js) in the `static` directory as explained in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: Hello it worked, but getting empty `tagbar` i.e. no labels in it, Is there any problem with the jquery that loads labels `tagbar`

Comment: Do you have any error in your browser dev console ?

Comment: No error at terminal in the browser all I see is this  https://s17.postimg.org/gd01tgzkf/textbox.png

Comment: Yes but in your browser JS / dev console ? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/ or https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console

Comment: I figured out the error, I added these lines and it worked `$('#tagbar').tagsinput({
   itemValue: 'value',
      itemText: 'text',
  });`